# Open Source flex time-series charts

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

Can anyone suggest an open-sourced time-series chart created using flex??
(With functionalities like the one on google/yahoo finance??)

Googling gives a lot of unnecessary data, I felt asking a question here would be more helpful.

Thanks

Neeraj

Answer (score 2):

[Axiis](http://www.axiis.org/) is an entire charting component set built on [Degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/)

It's open-source, has a line-series component and works with Flex 2 and 3.

**EDIT**: sorry , that's just Flex 3 (Degrafa works with both)